# How many words of length $n$ is it possible to create from $\{a,b,c\}$ without any “$c$”s after a “$b$”?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations, fibonacci-numbers, combinatorics-on-words

This post is a duplicate of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4052540/how-many-words-of-length-n-is-it-possible-to-create-from-a-b-c-without-any#4052540) post.

The question is,

> How many words of length $n$ is it possible to create from $\{a,b,c\}$ without any “$c$”s after a “$b$”?
>
> For example, the string $\color{blue}{\text{aabac}}$ is allowed but $\color{blue}{\text{cc}\color{red}{\text{bc}}\text{ab}}$ is not allowed because it contains $\text{bc}$ in that order. It could, however include $\text{cb}$.

I worked it for small values of $n$, and searched the resulting sequence on [OEIS](http://oeis.org/A001906).

I have been told of a method by forming a recurrence relation, which I have to still think upon, but the question is why is it related to even indexed fibonacci sequence? Is there any natural interpretation of this? I was amazed to see so many equivalent definitions of this problem in the OEIS page and this definition is one of them. I would be glad to see some different answers to this problem.

---

Here is another [related](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/686328/combinatorics-on-letters) post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $a_n$ be the number of such strings of length $n$, $b_n$ be the number of such strings which end with `b`, and $c_n$ the number of such strings which do not end with `b`.  Then

- $a_n = b_n+c_n$, since these are the  total number of such strings with length $n$
- $b_n = a_{n-1}$, since you can take a string of length $n-1$ and put a `b` on the end, and this gives $a_n = a_{n-1}+c_n$
- $c_n = b_{n-1}+2c_{n-1}$, since you can take a string of length $n-1$ ending in `b` and put an `a` on the end or you can take a  string of length $n-1$ not ending in `b` and put an `a` or a `c` on the end, and this gives $c_n =  a_{n-1}+c_{n-1}$

$c_n =  a_{n-1}+c_{n-1}$ and $a_n = a_{n-1}+c_n$ look Fibonacci-like.  Suppose we define $d_n$ such that $d_{2n-1}=c_n$ and $d_{2n}=a_n$.  Then we have $d_{2n-1}=d_{2n-2}+d_{2n-3}$ and $d_{2n}=d_{2n-1}+d_{2n-2}$ so combined $$d_{n}=d_{n-1}+d_{n-2}$$ which is the Fibonacci recurrence.

You also have to check the initial terms: $d_0=a_0=1$, $d_1=c_1=2$, $d_1=a_1=3$, so $d_n$ is the Fibonacci sequence offset by two positions, and $a_n=d_{2n}$ is the even terms of the Fibonacci sequence again with an offset.

Comment: Could you tell before forming the recurrence relation that it is related to fibonacci sequence?

Comment: I could tell at the start there would be a recurrence, but not what that recurrence would be until I looked at the details.  A slight adjustment (e.g. prohibiting `bc` and `cb`) might produce a different recurrence  (that example related to $1+\sqrt{2}$ rather than $\phi^2$)

Comment: I see, but what if there is an altogther different way of solving this problem, without forming recurrence relation?

Comment: @LightYagami perhaps you could show how you would define the Fibonacci sequence without a recurrence

Comment: What I mean is, could this problem be solved (not related to fibonacci sequence), for example, I started with cases, for example for $n=5$, I wrote $3^5-27-27-27+1-27+3+3$, basically I counted the cases for different positions of $bc$ and then subtracted from total cases...

Comment: I am satisfied by the recurrence relation argument now. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

One can quickly derive the recurrence relation for even-indexed Fibonacci numbers :

$$F_{2k+2}=F_{2k+1}+F_{2k}$$
$$F_{2k+2}=(F_{2k}+F_{2k-1})+F_{2k}$$
$$F_{2k+2}=(F_{2k}+(F_{2k}-F_{2k-2}))+F_{2k}$$
$$\Rightarrow \boxed{F_{2k+2}=3F_{2k}-F_{2k-2}} \tag{$k \ge 1$}$$

where $F_{0}=0$, $F_{2}=1$, $F_{4}=3$, $F_{6}=8$, $\ldots$

The problem satisfies the same recursive relation as given by @lulu :
$$\boxed{T_{n+1}=3T_{n}-T_{n-1}}$$

Also note, $T_1=3$, $T_2=3^2-1=8$.

The recurrence relation as well as the terms of sequence match. Hence the two sequences are identical.

Comment: It is true that one can see through it after forming a recurrence relation, but I wanted to know if one could argue *before*  forming the recursion, that is, some kind of combinatorial argument...

Comment: @LightYagami I'm afraid the combinatorial arguments would run along the lines of creating recurrence relation, no? Finding patterns in consecutive terms is same as finding recursive relation.

Comment: I solved for $n=5$ as Total cases- cases in which $bc$ occured, so I wrote $3^5-27-27-27+1-27+3+3$, kind of inclusion-exclusion, so what I mean is,  solving this problem in a completely different manner without forming recursive relation and then, if possible, relating it to fibonacci sequence, although I am convinced that for relating it to fibonacci sequence, one would have to resort to recurrence, but one could still think of a way to solve this problem without recursion.

Comment: The information content in two sequences is exactly same. If you could find a closed-form or any other indirect form of relation for current question, it would already (likely) be a known property satisfied by $F_{2n}$. I'm no expert but it is hard to imagine any other kind of combinatorial argument for this. In other words, the recurrence is the *easiest and most natural* way to see the two sequences are identical.

Comment: I see. Thank you. Now I am satisfied.